# Why this circle is red?

Tags: android

I try to make a gradient circle with this code:

```
RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 40, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW}, new float[] {3,4}, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

This only makes a circle with red. Not a gradient with yellow why?

Comment: Try setting the positions parameter to null and see if that does anything.

Comment: this made it yellow .D

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your float[] parameter is bogus... shouldn't those values be between 0 and 1? So to have a RED center and a YELLOW edge you'd use float[] {0,1}.

(This is a bit of a guess... I haven't run the code to check and the documentation is less than clear).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
RadialGradient gradient1 =new android.graphics.RadialGradient(0, 0,40,Color.RED,Color.YELLOW, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Comment: maybe 40 is to big, thats the radius of the gradient, try using a smaller number